# How to avoid single quotes in file name during python saving file?

Tags: python, ls, filenames

If Python saves file on extended 4(Linux) partition that contains unusual symbol(so far uncovered square brackets [] ). It automatically quotes file name.

For example:

```
file[].txt
```

will be saved as

```
'file[].txt'
```

In Linux, extended 4 partition "file[].txt" is a valid file name.

Why is it happening and can it be avoided?
I can create a work around, by removing first and last symbol of file name, but I plan to run my app on many platforms. So I'd rather nip it in the bud early.

Python3 is used on AMD64 platform Linux Gentoo with ext4 partition.

python code:

```
    print('\ndebug:triggered sf mode, name of file below \n')
    clientsocket, addr = serversocket.accept()
    filename = clientsocket.recv(10240)
    filename = filename.decode('UTF-8')
    app_output(filename)
    mode = 'valid'
    clientsocket.close()

    clientsocket, addr = serversocket.accept()
    incmdata = '1'
    somefile = open(filename, 'w+')
    somefile.close()
    while len(incmdata) !=0:
        incmdata = clientsocket.recv(1024 * 8)
        print('this is filename: ', filename)
        somefile=open(filename, 'ab')
        somefile.write(incmdata)
        somefile.close()
    app_output('file supposedly recieved')
```

filename variable is something client sends to miniserver.(actually client catches positional variable)

this is output:

```
file[].txt
this is filename:  file[].txt
this is filename:  file[].txt
```

also, relevant part of

```
ls -lah

-rw-r--r--  1 dimko dimko        269 Sep 11 10:00  file_open.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 dimko dimko         93 Sep 11 09:05  file_open.txt~
-rw-r--r--  1 dimko dimko          5 Sep 14 11:24 'file[].txt'
drwxr-xr-x  3 dimko dimko       4096 Sep 14 11:21  .idea
-rw-r--r--  1 dimko dimko       7635 Sep 14 11:20  LanSwissKnife.py
```

Comment: Where are you seeing these quotes? In the output of `ls`?

Comment: its not my code, i can reproduce it in 4 lines of code.
dimko@(none)dimko's Desktop ~/PycharmProjects/p2p_message_a7 $ python3
Python 3.6.5 (default, Apr 19 2018, 00:31:26) 
[GCC 6.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> filename = '[somefile]'
>>> f=open(filename, 'w')
>>> f.write ('something')
9
>>> f.close()
>>>

ls -lah gives this:
-rw-r--r--  1 dimko dimko    9 Sep 14 11:40 '[somefile]'

Comment: `man ls`, `/--quoting-style`

Answer (score 7):

The actual filename is:

```
file[].txt
```

Your python program is not at any fault here. The quotes are done by `ls`.

I was able reproduce it using:

```
ls -lah --quoting-style=shell
```

but when I choose `literal` as a quoting style:

```
ls -lah --quoting-style=literal
```

then the files with `[` or `]` are listed without quotes.
Note that you `ls` might have different default arguments on different systems.

Answer (score 6):

The fact that the quoted filename is still aligned with the other filenames in your `ls -lah` output makes me think that the quotes are probably added by your `ls` command, and are not a real part of the filename. The purpose is probably to indicate "this filename needs quoting on the command line, or else unexpected things may happen."

Try creating a similar filename on the command line and see what happens:

```
touch /tmp/file\[\].txt
ls -lah /tmp
```